# Smallest sum of graph weight, where each node are connected (like a network)

Tags: algorithm

What algorithm I can use for problem like this:

Have a graph positive weighted, i want to know a smallest
possible sum of weights where each node are connected (connected like a network, where each node is a eg. network device).

In this network each node can be connected with other node by some other other nodes in way. But all nodes from input graph must be in a network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the resulting network you want is a minimum spanning tree, which has two well-known algorithms: [Kruskal's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) and [Prim's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a minimum spanning tree (MST).